# Use three 10's to create 950

Tags: mathematics

Here is an interesting puzzle that I found:

You have three 10's. It looks like this:

### | 0 | 0 | 0

Add one stroke to the diagram to create **950**.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The stroke to add is

> at the top of the second |, turning it into a T. The message then spells "10 TO 10", or 9:50 (10 minutes until 10:00).

Comment: That is correct! That's actually what I found. :D